# C#: Override operator of existing class

Tags: c#, overloading, operator-keyword

For unit tests of a class, I'd like to introduce an intuitive short-cut syntax similar to the following:

```
// true iff (from t1 in table1 select t1).ToSql() delivers the given string
Check((from t1 in table1 select t1) == "SELECT * FROM Table1");
```

I've written an extension for `IQueryable` objects named `ToSql()` that transforms the given query into SQL. The unit test should check whether the actual result equals the reference string.

Therefore, I need to define the operator "==" for either `IQueryable` or `string`. How can I do this without encapsulating either of the objects into a custom data structure?

Comment: You can't currently, but it might be coming soon. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/11159

Comment: Any reason you're not using regular `Assert.Equals` or whatever? I would favour adding a method accepting expected and actual values over trying to work with operator overloading.

Comment: Wouldn't something like `Assert.Equals((from t1 in table1 select t1).ToSql(), "SELECT * FROM Table1")` do?

Comment: My personal opinion is that operator overloading often breaks https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: Well, you might be right. It's kinda abusing the notation and in this case the gain is small. Last week, I did the same for Boolean expressions. There, I encapsulated them into a data structure for which I defined operators like ==, !=, &, |, ... to do this, which gave me expressions like `Check((p | q) & r == (q & r) | (p & r))` and honestly, this is far more readable, understandable and maintainable than nested `Expression` and `Tuple` factory method/constructor calls longer than any monitor can display. So, I like it actually.